# Youtube api returns error when tried to execute using accesstoken retrieved Service Account

Tags: youtube-api, service-accounts

I was able to retrieve access-token using Google Service Account, when I tried to use the same access-token to with Youtube API I'm getting error as mentioned below:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>NoLinkedYouTubeAccount</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>NoLinkedYouTubeAccount</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

while retrieving access-token through service account i used scope value as
    "http://gdata.youtube.com" and i was able to fetch access-token but the same accesstoken when used to access  youtube userprofile api i.e
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2" above mentioned error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using an unlinked Google Account with the API v2.0

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html

*API v2.0 supports all authenticated operations for users with YouTube accounts, which could also be called linked Google Accounts, but doesn’t support any authenticated operations for unlinked Google Accounts. If the authentication token for a v2.0 API request identifies an unlinked Google Account, the API will return a 401 NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error.*